# How to allow dropdowns in the sidebar navigation TOC of the Furo Sphinx theme?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to allow users to have dropdown menus (with a little arrow) in the TOC tree that is in the navigation sidebar in the Furo theme. I saw that some themes like book-theme allow for this by specifying a theme option, but I am currently puzzled as to how this can be done for the Furo theme.

I tried looking into whether there were theme options or I adding the content tree directly, but I failed to find any. I tried adding `sphrinxcontrib.fulltoc` extensions, which works without Furo, but throws an error when used in combination with Furo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Me too, I know people used the Furo theme with arrows for dropdown, See [this one](https://virtuallab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). And my website with the same themes doesn't use the arrow. strange

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with adding a dropdown in the sidebar using furo. Here is what I did:

I added the following extensions in my conf.py:

myst_enable_extensions = [
"html_image",
"html_admonition",
"colon_fence",
"sphinx.ext.autodoc",
"sphinx.ext.extlinks",
"sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
"sphinx.ext.mathjax",
"sphinx.ext.todo",
"sphinx.ext.viewcode",
"furo.sphinxext",
"myst_parser",
"sphinx_copybutton",
"sphinx_design",
"sphinx_inline_tabs"]

I'm not sure which one of these actually creates the arrow for the dropdown, but it worked for me.

I looked at how they did it in the furo docs to get the answer: https://pradyunsg.me/furo/

Github for furo docs: https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/tree/main/docs